# Can Scala's Actor framework handle 10.000 actors without stack problems?

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor

I want to do a multi-agent simulation containing about 10.000 agents (machine and product agents) using the Scala Actor framework.

As I understand, if there are lots of actors passing messages around, can it run out of stack due the recursion?

If so, how can I increase the stack sizes for the underlying worker threads?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actor framework has been designed to handle this - in fact, it can handle this with only one thread, assuming you use the `loop-react` pattern as follows:

```
import actors._
import actors.Actor._

val a = actor {
  loop {
    react {
      case ABC => //Handle here

    }
  }
}
```

On pp 590-593 of *Programming in Scala* this is discussed in more detail: basically the `react` method never returns normally (it terminates with an exception) and therefore its call stack does not need to be preserved. You can think of it as looping forever.

Comment: Thank you. I might have overlooked that sentence in the book. And what about the way to increase the worker threads stack size - just curious?

Comment: have a look at: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_5_final/src/actors/scala/actors/FJTaskScheduler2.scala?view=markup. You'll see that you can define system properties like "actors.maxPoolSize" etc

Comment: Although the point is to let the FJTaskScheduler decide on how much concurrency your system supports (i.e. how many available processors there are)

Comment: I don't see an option setting the Thread stack size there. But thanks.

Comment: Sorry - wasn't reading your comment properly. Surely thread stacks sizes are controlled at the JVM level and hence configurable as any Java program would be (-Xss or something like that)

Comment: -Xss is a way. I thought more like a ThreadFactory similarly as in java's ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: I didn't realize you could set stack size in a java executor